# What happened to the Watson visualize service?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I noticed the Watson API for Personality Insights that can visualize the profile in a cool D3.js chart has been deprecated.  What are the plans to support this going forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of an API, we have made it available as a client side library. Its available in the sample application code: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/personality-insights-nodejs .

"The visualize API is now deprecated and will be removed entirely in a future release. You can use the `personality.js` JavaScript file that is provided with the sample application to achieve similar results from the client. The `textsummary.js` JavaScript file provides additional formatting for the results of the service"